# Can't get the previous and next posts permalink

Tags: loop, permalinks, navigation, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I tried to get the next and previous URL, and create a navigation. But it seems to only retrieve the permalink from the two first posts (but not the others recents posts).

I have 5 posts (ID = 25, 86, 80, 75, 45). When I am on the first post (ID = 25) and I click on previous post, I am going to post ID = 45, and after when I click on previous it stay on the same page.

```
<?php 
  if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

  $prev = get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(false,'',false));
  $next = get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(false,'',true)); ?>

  <li class="post-link">
    <a class="prev" href="<?php echo $prev; ?>">
      <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="post-link">
    <a class="next" href="<?php echo $next; ?>">
      <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>
  </li>

<?php endwhile; endif; get_footer(); ?>
```

I also tried to put the code after the while loop.

**Update**
I solved the problem. When I published my posts, they had all the same date, so it displayed only one post from this date. I changed with a different day date, and it works! My bad.

Comment: is that in an index template or in the single.php template? have you reviewed http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination

Comment: Yes, it's on the index page. I already take a look at this page, but I didn't find anything to fix the problem I think.

Answer (score 1):

You could use different code. As an example, this modified code from the Twenty Fourteen parent theme which i tested on other themes works well.

Add this to a new file named template-tags.php

```
<?php

if ( ! function_exists( 'wpsites_post_nav' ) ) :

function wpsites_post_nav() {

$previous = ( is_attachment() ) ? get_post( get_post()->post_parent ) : get_adjacent_post( false, '', true );
$next     = get_adjacent_post( false, '', false );

if ( ! $next && ! $previous ) {
    return;
}

?>
<nav class="navigation post-navigation" role="navigation">
    <div class="nav-links">
        <?php
            previous_post_link( '%link', __( '<span class="meta-nav">Previous Post</span>%title', 'wpsites' ) );
            next_post_link( '%link', __( '<span class="meta-nav">Next Post</span>%title', 'wpsites' ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .nav-links -->
</nav><!-- .navigation -->
<?php
}
endif;
```

Creates a template tag which you can use in a custom function or directly in your single.php file:

**Child themes functions.php file**

```
require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/template-tags.php' );
```

**Alternatively - Parent themes functions.php file**

```
require get_template_directory() . '/template-tags.php' ;
```

**Single.php template tag**

```
<?php wpsites_post_nav(); ?>
```

Comment: I wrote an update on my first post. Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should use   &  for the navigation. 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_post_link
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/previous_post_link

Thanks

Comment: Already test, inside the while loop, after, nothing works. Plus I don't want to get the full `<a>` tag, just the link for the previous and next post.